# How to transform a tuple per RDD to another to group protocol data?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a tuple :

```
val key = List(protocol, source, destination, port)
```

for each rdd.

I need to map this to

```
(protocol ,List(source, destination, port))
```

which should be then reduced to a list of

```
List(source,(destination1, destination2))
```

grouping by `protocol`.

Finally, it should be like a tuple with

```
(protocol, (source, (destination1, destination2)))
```

The output I need is as follows:

```
{(tcp , (xx.xx.xx.xx ,(ww.ww.w.w,rr.rr.r.r))) , (udp,(yy.yy.yy.yy,(ww.ww.w.w,rr.rr.r.r)))}
```

The code is:

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, PcapPacket, StringDecoder,PcapDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Map(topics -> 1), StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
val m = lines.window(Seconds(4), Seconds(4)).mapPartitions(x =>
          x.map{y => analysis(y._2)}
        )
```

This will give (5 fields as output)

Comment: It should really be closed, but since it got an answer I'm for leaving it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by (protocol, source) at first, then group by (protocol). E.g.,

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val testData = List(
  ("tcp", "xx.xx.xx.xx", "ww.ww.w.w", 12345),
  ("tcp", "xx.xx.xx.xx", "rr.rr.r.r", 12345),
  ("udp", "yy.yy.yy.yy", "ww.ww.w.w", 12345),
  ("udp", "yy.yy.yy.yy", "rr.rr.r.r", 12345)
)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(testData)
val resultRDD = rdd.map {
  case (protocol, source, destination, port) => ((protocol, source), destination)
}.groupByKey().map {
  case ((protocol, source), destinations) => (protocol, (source, destinations.toSeq))
}.groupByKey()
resultRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

However, you need to make sure the data for a protocol can be fit to memory.

Comment: val m = lines.window(Seconds(4),Seconds(4)).mapPartitions(x=>x.map{y=>
     analysis(y._2)
   })  This will give ("tcp", "xx.xx.xx.xx", "ww.ww.w.w", 12345) as output. But I am not able to do the above with this output dstream. Cannot resolve symbol groupByKey,collect..  Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you forget to `import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._`?

Comment: What's the type of `m`? Do you import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._?

Comment: m is of type DStream[(String,String,String,Int,Int)] . Yes, imported Streamingcontext .

Comment: 5 fields? Then you need to update the `map` function accordingly

Comment: Yea..thats updated.but still I am not able to group it. groupbykey is not available. groupby is available. how to do the same with groupby function?

Comment: Could you add your current codes to the question so that I can try to figure out the problem?

Comment: Error:(45, 41) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)
 required: List[Any]
      val s =analysis(packet).map{ case (protocol, source, destination, sport, dport) => ((protocol, source), destination,sport,dport)}.groupBy(_._1).map{
                                        ^

Comment: What's the return type of `analysis(packet)`. Looks you are confused with some Scala syntax, not a problem of Spark.

Comment: it is list(String,String.String,Int,int)

Comment: I guess you mean it's List[Any]. Then you should use `map(list => (list(0).toString, list(1).toString, list(2).toString, list(3).toInt, list(4).toInt))` to convert the list to a tuple5

Comment: How would the reduce functions be if reducebykeyand window is used? m.mapPartitions(x=>x.map(y=>List(y._1,(y._2,y._3,y._4,y._5)))).reduceByKeyAndWindow()